# Highchart bars lower half gets disappeared

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Many times lower half of my highchart bar gets disappear on drill down and then drill up . I have even disabled animation on plotoptions but that doesn't solve my issue ,I am not able to replicate the issue on jsfiddle but not sure if it's due to high charts issue.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart : {
                    type : 'column',
                    events : {
                        drilldown : function(e) {
                            this.xAxis[0].setTitle({
                                text : 'Error Type'
                            });
                            this.setTitle({ text: "Error Distribution by Specifics" });
                             this.xAxis[0].update({
                                  tickInterval: 0,
                          });
                             
                        },
                        drillup : function(e) {
                            
                            
                            this.xAxis[0].setTitle({
                                text : 'Mean Absolute Error (in days)'
                            });
                            this.setTitle({ text: "Error Distribution by Days" });
                             this.xAxis[0].update({
                                  tickInterval: 0.5,
                          });
                        }
                    }
                }, 
    
    title: {
        text: 'Error Distribution (Days)'
    },
                xAxis : {
                    title : {
                        text : 'Mean Absolute Error in Days'
                    },
                    type: 'category',
                    tickInterval : 0.50,
                    crosshair : true
                },
                yAxis : {
                    title : {
                        text : 'Predicted Error Count'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                                animation:false
                    }
                },
                tooltip : {
                    headerFormat : '',
                    shared : true,
                    pointFormat : 'Predicted Error Count : {point.y}'
                    
                },

    series: [
        {
            name: "Error Distribution by Days Report",
            data: [
                
   
   {
      "x":2,
      "y":500,
      "drilldown":"2",
      "name":2
   },
   
   {
      "x":3.5,
      "y":500,
      "drilldown":"3.5",
      "name":3.5
   },
   {
      "x":10,
      "y":3508,
      "drilldown":"10",
      "name":"More"
   }

            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
        series:[
   {
      "name":"2",
      "id":"2",
      "pointWidth":30,
      "data":[
         [
            "Error A",
            500
         ]
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"10",
      "id":"10",
      "pointWidth":30,
      "data":[
         [
            "Error A",
            501
         ],
         [
            "Error B",
            1001
         ],
         [
            "Error C",
            1
         ]
      ]
   },
   
   {
      "name":"3.5",
      "id":"3.5",
      "pointWidth":30,
      "data":[
         [
            "Error B",
            500
         ]
      ]
   }
]
        
    }
});
```

Image when page is loaded is below
[image]

Now when I do a drill down and then again drill up the lower half dissappears

[image]

Same issue occurs during drill down also .

Comment: Per your description, could this be a highchart bug?

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue here?

Comment: No I am not able to replicate on jsfiddle

Comment: I reproduced your code in the jsfiddle, but it seems that everything works as it should be. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nsge8q0a/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding clip:false in plot options, the issue was found out that while drill down it generated extra  clipPath ,removing it solve the issue